# NoSuchElementException when setting a timeout on the socket

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, java.util.scanner

I wanted to set a timeout when a client read. the routine supposed to throw an InterruptedIOException but instead it throws NoSuchElementException on `System.out.println("echo: " + _in.nextLine());` what am I doing wrong ?

this is my methode

```
public void startUserInput()
{
    try {
        _out = new PrintWriter(_echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        _in  = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(_echoSocket.getInputStream()));

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        while (stdIn.hasNextLine()) {
            _out.println(stdIn.nextLine());
            System.out.println("echo: " + _in.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Input: ");
        }
        stdIn.close();

    }catch (InterruptedIOException exception){
        System.err.println("The server is not responding " + _serverHostname);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error"  + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }}
```

and this is my connection

```
public boolean establishConnection()
{
    System.out.println ("Connecting to the host " +
            this.getServerHostname() + " au port " + this.getServerPort());

    try {
        _echoSocket = new Socket();
        _echoSocket = new Socket(this.getServerHostname(), this.getServerPort());
        _echoSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        System.out.println(_echoSocket.getOutputStream());
        return _echoSocket.isConnected();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown host: " + this.getServerHostname());
        return false;



    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while connecting to the server : " + 
                this.getServerHostname() + ":" + this.getServerPort());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when you invoked `_in.nextLine()` there is no line to be read in from the from the Scanner object _in.

What you did in the while loop was to check for `stdIn.hasNextLine()` but you did not check if `_in` has a nextLine() that can be read.

For details on the exception, you can check out:

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

hope it helps :) Cheers!

Comment: Using the 'hasNextLine()' condition before reading _in didn't throw the NoSuchElementException, neither the InterruptedIOException

Comment: I think I am gonna process the timeout exception inside the NoSuchElementException, unless you have better solution :)

Comment: 'hasNextLine()' does not throw NoSuchElementException. It will throw IllegalStateException if the scanner is closed. You probably should check with: _in.hasNextLine() before you invoke _in.nextLine(). Hope it helps :)